# neo4j: how to much a few different paths?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a directed graph representing page content. Page can contain pages, components (of different types) and files. Component can point to files they are using (from the same page). files have no children. So:

```
page --> page --> page
 |        |---> component-----|
 |        |                   v
 |        |----------------> file
 |        |---> file
 |
 |--> component
 |--> component --------|
 |                      v
 |-------------------> file
```

Now I want to query for a page (by its property uuid) and get:

1. the page node
2. its all components and files used by those components
3. all direct subpages and their components of specific type (label or property) and files referenced by those components

currently I match by `-[:has_child*0..4]->` and filter in the backend. can it be done by Neo4j itself?

Comment: Are you trying to get these requirements using 3 different queries? Or only one query? Also, its a good idea to [create a console](http://console.neo4j.org/) with a sample data set and the expected result.